# LOAD DATA INFILE LINES TERMINATD doesn't work with \n

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a csv file, that I want to import to MySQL, but LINES TERMINATED doesn't work with '\n'. I tried to replace \n with '\r' or '\r\n', but it still doesn't work.

If I open my file in HEX editor it is obvious, that my Java App (that writes this file) works fine ('\n' terminators are highlighted).
[image]

But when I run

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/vsafonov/testDir/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE express.objs 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I get

[image]

If I replace '\n' for new lines with some symbol (for example ';'), LOAD DATA INFILE works fine. But I have no ideas, why it is impossible to load file with '\n' line terminator. Some thoughts?

Table's CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_objs` (
                                      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                      `object_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                                      `next_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                                      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My file example:

```
id,object_id,next_id
"1866227","98363301","156715750"
"293","171","454"
"1890275","171","177646470"
```

Comment: Provide 1) complete table's CREATE TABLE; 2) textual file data example (3-5 rows).

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @Akina it's just typo here, because I was trying all combinations when just '\n' hasn't worked. So, space isn't a trouble

Comment: @Akina reopen my question please, because it was just a typo.

Comment: I have no such permission.

Comment: @Akina ok, I added CREATE TABLE and text file content example to my question. I tried LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/vsafonov/testDir/test.csv' INTO TABLE express.objs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY CHAR(10) IGNORE 1 LINES; but got an error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHAR(10) IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1"

Comment: *but got an error* This means that the terminator is accepted literally, and function is not applicable... I have recreated your table and data file, and the file was imported successfully.

Comment: @Akina it seems so, but why does it happen and how to fix it, that's the question. Can this be connected with version of mysql (5.7.33)?

Comment: I doubt. PS. The file HEX content does not match textual sample.

Comment: @Akina ye, that's bigger version of file, I should replace it with actual one.

Comment: Мож эта... на ru.stackoverflow.com разумнее переползти?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237117/discussion-between-vladimir-safonov-and-akina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me with query worked

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/vsafonov/testDir/test.csv'
INTO TABLE express.objs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

Default terminator worked fine with my '/n'.

Terminator in my query was accepted literally (didn't understand why).